# Batch - find process that contains name in tasklist

Tags: batch-file, contains

I have a constantly changing process name where the only constant in it is the substring "-Installer". For other proccesess I have used `eq` like this:

```
tasklist /fi "ImageName eq %INSTALLER_NAME%" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I %INSTALLER_NAME%>NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    echo %INSTALLER_NAME% is running, possible installation going on
    exit /B
)
```

How do I change it to find a process that contains the substring?

Comment: Have you read the output from `tasklist /?`? Did you consider or try, ```tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq *-installer" ...```?
```

Comment: I've tries ```tasklist /fi "ImageName eq %VPU_NAME%" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I %VPU_NAME%>NUL```
where ```set INSTALLER_NAME="*-installer"``` but got ```File not found - "*-installer"*```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Yuki1112. It appears, although not specifically mentioned in the help information, that the wildcard option only works when suffixed, not when prefixed or used midstring. I would say however that it would be far better for us to offer a more robust solution for your specific task, if you were to submit a few possible image/process names, in order to ensure that only the target is identified. Would it be possible for you to [Edit] your question, to include those?